# How to choose random cells in VBA?

Tags: vba

I have a question about how to letting VBA choose random numbers from my sheet. I have a column "A" with person id for delayed students, column "B" with person id for non-delayed students, "C" column with student id, column "D" sum of the grades for each person id and column "E" with a number of attempts. 
I want to let VBA find a random person ID and then choose the other columns from the same personid.

ex. if the VBA randomly choose person id for delayed students: 285639, then it has to show the student id and the sum of the grades for that specific person id. and if it chooses a non-delayed person, an error message must be shown to the user.

Until now I have used the following codes, which runs perfectly, but I don't know how to let it know to find the specific information for that person id. Finally, it should appear in a message box.

I hope some one can help.

```
    Dim RNG As Range
    Set RNG = Range("A2:B5478")

    Dim randomCell As Long
        randomCell = Int(Rnd * RNG.Cells.Count) + 1

    With RNG.Cells(randomCell)
        .Select
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! So the random part is actually covered and you're looking for a way to find a row of data that is linked to a specific person/id? It's a bit unclear to me what your actual problem is...

Comment: You got a two column range there. Assuming you got the personID in A, and the name in B, maybe you want to get `Rnd * rng.Rows.count` to get a row number (rather than a cell number), and then from that row get the value of the second cell. That way, you get the column B that belongs to the random cell in column A.

Comment: Yes, with the code above I have been able to find a random person id. But I need to find the specific information to the found person ID that has just been found. However, the information should only be displayed if the person ID is a delayed student (Column A) otherwise it must display an error message. @GolezTrol

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this will

- Select a random Delayed Student Id (col A) - eliminates the need for an error message
- Find Student ID in column C
- Activates Delayed Student ID cell
- Highlight the row for that specific Delayed Student ID (columns C, D and E) in Yellow
- Display a Message Box with Student ID and Sum of Grades for that specific Person ID

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectDelayed1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, delayedCol As Range, personIdCol As Range
    Dim rndCell As Range, foundId As Variant, msg As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet    'Or: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set delayedCol = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set personIdCol = ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)

    Do
        Set rndCell = delayedCol.Cells(Int(Rnd * delayedCol.Cells.Count) + 1)
        foundId = Application.Match(rndCell, personIdCol, 0)
    Loop While IsError(foundId)

    rndCell.Activate

    With personIdCol
        msg = .Cells(1) & ": " & rndCell.Value2
        With .Cells(foundId)
            msg = msg & ", " & personIdCol.Cells(1).Offset(, 1) & ": " & .Offset(, 1)
            Union(rndCell, ws.Range(.Cells, .Resize(, 3))).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End With
        MsgBox msg, vbOKOnly, .Cells(1) & ": " & rndCell.Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Result

[image: TestResult]

---

It can be modified to select a random Student ID from Col **A or B**, and show an error if it's B

Comment: thank you, it helped a lot.
If I have more information I would like to find and all the informations must be displayed in a Message Box where should I write the extra informations I have? @paulbica

Comment: Depending on where you have the extra information, but you can add more by editing the lines that start with *"msg = msg & ...*", Example: if I wanted to add the word "**test**" after "*Sum if Grades: 7*" in the message box I would use this line just above the line starting with "_MsgBox msg, ..._": `msg = msg & ", test"`. If I wanted to add a new line of text: `msg = msg & vbNewLine & "Test"`